# React Native - Reanimated Bottom Sheet: Content in Snapable Container only scrollable on iOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

I have a container with 3 snap points which also contains a scrollView where I display more information. For some reason, this scrollview only works on iOS and not on Android. However, on Android the scrolling works when I do a sort of vertical pinch to zoom move on the screen. On iOS everything works absolutely seamlessly.

Here the repo for the reanimated-bottom-sheet:
https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet

I already tried playing around with the props provided on the repository page of the Bottom Sheet library as well as attempted using these props as mentioned in other StackOverflow questions which sadly didn´t do the trick for me. On Android only either the scrolling worked or the snap points. Never the two (Only the two-finger pinching).

[Can't scroll Flatlist inside react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155874/cant-scroll-flatlist-inside-react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet)

```
enabledInnerScrolling={true}
enabledContentGestureInteraction={false}
```

Help is much appreciated since it´s the final project of our WebDev course and we don´t have too much time left >.<
Here is the code snippet.

````
  const bs = React.createRef();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bs}
        snapPoints={['85%', '39%', '17%']}
        initialSnap={1}
        renderContent={renderContent}
        enabledInnerScrolling={true}
      />
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => bs.current.snapTo(0)}>
        <Image
          style={styles.background}
          source={require('../assets/images/TEST-flower-02.jpg')}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
```
````

Comment: You could try https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-scroll-bottom-sheet, it's been designed with scrollable content in mind

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `FlatList` component from `react-native-gesture-handler` **instead** of the default `FlatList` module exported in `react-native`.
This should get your scrollView working on Android

```
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

...
const renderContent = () => (
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
  />);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `import ScrollView from "react-native-gesture-handler".` It worked for me